# Sum Value1 in Table 1 WHEN Value2 exists in Table2

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have 2 tables. One Table contains a `Customer_ID, Product_Code, and Price_Paid`.

Table 2 is a single column with `Product_Code` that are specific to a certain type of Product.

There are thousands of product_codes in Table 1 but only about 500 in Table2.

I'd like to write a query that returns me the sum of Price_Paid per customer ONLY when the Product_Code exists in Table 2.

Would I need to do this in a subquery or is it possible to use a CASE statement to search the  product code in Table 2 for a match in Table 1 before summing.

Thanks

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried ? Looks like a simple `INNER JOIN` with `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [T]he sum of Price_Paid per customer ONLY when the Product_Code exists in Table 2.

Unless I'm missing something, that's just an `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT
  Customer_ID,
  SUM(Price_Paid) AS SumOfPrice
FROM
  Table1 as t1
  INNER JOIN
  Table2 as t2
    ON t2.Product_Code = t1.Product_Code
GROUP BY 
  Customer_ID;
```

Comment: Dont you need a `GROUP BY` ?

Comment: Yup. That’s what I get for going too fast. Thanks, @JuanCarlosOropeza.

Answer (score 1):

While there's no problem with @Eric Brandt's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54872872/451601), it relies `Product_Code` being unique in products table.  A more general solution is to use `EXISTS`.  And I think you might want sum by product, not just customer?

```
SELECT
  Customer_ID, Product_Code
  SUM(Price_Paid) AS SumOfPrice
FROM
  Table1 as t1
WHERE EXISTS (
    select 1 from Table2
    where Product_Code = t1.Product_Code
)
GROUP BY 
  Customer_ID, Product_Code;
```

Comment: You're absolutely right on both counts, @James, but I took the "intro level answer to an intro level question" route. +1 from me, though, for providing the "better" answer for anyone who might stumble across this one later on.